# multiple cookies in vbscript

Tags: cookies, vbscript, internet-explorer-10

I faced the following problem:

I need to parse many cookies in vbscript and this is my code so far:

```
Dim url : url = "https://MYURL"
Dim http
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
http.open "GET", url, False
http.Send
Dim aRes : aRes = Split(http.getAllResponseHeaders(), vbCrLf)

Dim i
For i = 0 To UBound(aRes)
   aRes(i) = Mid(aRes(i), Len(header) + 1, Len(aRes(i)))
Next
Set http = Nothing

Dim cookie
For Each cookie In aRes
    TextBoxTestOutput.Text = TextBoxTestOutput.Text + VBNewline + cookie
Next
```

This just returns the content of one cookie, but there are two and the one that's been shown has "/something" path while the other one has "/".

I think this is a IE related Problem. I am using IE10.

What could be the cause for not getting the other cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script receives cookies via http-GET. That's why it does not get a previously set cookie which is not sent in the answer of this GET-request.